# jCarousel v.0.3.0 - How to hide prev when hit the fist item of list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

i'm trying to use jCarousel but I need to remove the prev control when the carousel hits the first item of the list.

I tried (view fiddle) but it only happens when I click one time more on prev control.

Here is the fiddle:

[Preview](http://bit.ly/1h2OLRy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because it takes 100 milliseconds to run the sliding animation, and the if statement is being run at the beginning, when the CSS top property has -60 px.

If you set a timeout call, it will work fine:

```
$('a.glist-prev').click(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (parseInt($('ul.ganhadores-list').css('top')) === 0) {
            $('a.glist-prev').addClass('disabled');
        }        
    },200);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wDu6Z/

**Update:** My answer is related to the reason why your code doesn't work. It's not an implementation. You can find a proper example on the [official website](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/basic/).

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.jcarousel').jcarousel();

        $('.jcarousel-control-prev')
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
                $(this).removeClass('inactive');
            })
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
                $(this).addClass('inactive');
            })
            .jcarouselControl({
                target: '-=1'
            });

        $('.jcarousel-control-next')
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
                $(this).removeClass('inactive');
            })
            .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
                $(this).addClass('inactive');
            })
            .jcarouselControl({
                target: '+=1'
            });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but it's not working here. Need the final prev click :/

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what "Need the final prev click" means.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I just needed to set the time for more than 100 ;)

Comment: I missed that, wanted to make it 200; updated my answer accordingly.